# seeing output of C code in Xcode on mac

Tags: c, xcode

I'm using Xcode to write C code. Firstly, it took me for ages to figure out that I need to go to Product->Edit Scheme->Select Executable in order to run C executables.

I have a lot of source files and each one has a main so is there any way to run C source files by just selecting them from left-hand pane and pressing Run? Is there a simpler workflow?

Answer (score 1):

Add new target and select the source file which you need and assign to this target and run.